# How to ignore certain fields while JSON deserialization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, deserialization, rails-activerecord

I have a json that I want to deserialize and save to the database. Here's a code snippet:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    json_articles = JSON.parse('json_string_here')
    json_articles['articles'].each do |article|
      Article.new(article).save
    end
  end
end
```

During deserialization, I get the following error for the reason that in the database schema `article_link` field is absent:

> unknown attribute 'article_link' for Article.

So, here are my questions:

1. If I want to ignore this field when deserializing how it can be achieved?
2. And if there are comments on the code presented above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following

```
Article.new(article.except('article_link')).save
```

You could shorten this line further by using

```
Article.create(article.except('article_link'))
```

This does `new` and `save` at the same time. If you have any validations in your Article model, both variants might not be saved to database if these fail. You might want to check for such errors here.